# Unity3D why my client can't call cmd method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

My problem is: I have a player which includes a weapon object,and my weapon object includes the following script:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    AutomaticFirearmShoot();
}


public void AutomaticFirearmShoot()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > _nextFire)
    {
        _nextFire = Time.time + _fireRate;      
        _player.GetComponent<NetworkShootManager>().CmdShoot();

    }

}
```

My root player includes this script too:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class NetworkShootManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
private void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }
}

[Command]
public void CmdShoot()
{

   Debug.Log("shooting");

}


}
```

So when i build the game, only the host player can call the `CmdShoot` method.

Also, my player has network identity component.

Answer (score 0):

You should be available to do that using [`Networking.NetworkBehaviour.isServer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour-isServer.html) (this is obsolete).

The implementation could be something like this:

```
[Command]
public void CmdShoot()
{

   if(!isServer)
       return; // If this is not being executed by the hoster then exit the method call.

   Debug.Log("shooting");

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You may post a clear answer. Do you want that only the hoster can access the CmdShoot command or everyone?

Comment: i want to everyone.

Comment: Try to remove `if(!isLocalPlayer)` condition from `Update()`

Answer (score 0):

UNet uses [Remote Actions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html) to perform calls on the server and on the clients.
In your case you are using `[Command]` which performs a call on the server.
You will have to use. `[ClientRpc]` to call on clients. but remember, a client cannot call to other clients without passing through a server. So you will have to use a `[Command]` method, that then calls `[ClientRpc]`.

Additionally, Unitys network manager component, lets the host becomes both a client and the server, so the host will be able to see all server calls and such, while other clients will not.